# Java equivalent of PHP's DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR?

Tags: java, php, filepath

In PHP, to ensure that a path contains OS-appropriate directory separator characters, one would use the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant (although it [might not always be necessary to do so](http://alanhogan.com/tips/php/directory-separator-not-necessary)).

Is there an equivalent entity in Java?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two system-dependant constants provided by the `java.io.File` class:

- [`java.io.File.separator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) is a string containing the system-dependent name-separator character (ie "/" for Unix, "\" for Windows)
- [`java.io.File.pathSeparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#pathSeparator) is a string containing the system-dependent path-separator character (ie ":" for Unix, ";" for Windows)

Comment: [This comment refers to a previous, incorrect version of this answer] `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is a forward or backward slash to separate directories within a path. `java.io.File.pathSeparator` is the character for separating entire paths, usually a colon or semicolon.

Comment: Just to make it complete: Its like `PATH_SEPARATOR` in PHP (but thats not asked here).

Comment: Thanks, I clarified my response a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Google](http://www.google.de/search?q=java%20system%20dependent%20directory%20separator) takes me to [java.io.File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

> **public static final char separatorChar**
>
> The system-dependent default name-separator character. This field is initialized to contain the first character of the value of the system property file.separator. On UNIX systems the value of this field is '/'; on Microsoft Windows systems it is '\'.
>   See Also:
>   System.getProperty(java.lang.String)
>
> **public static final String separator**
>
> The system-dependent default name-separator character, represented as a string for convenience. This string contains a single character, namely separatorChar.

Comment: Indeed it does.  Thanks for the search string suggestion; I was searching for variations of "java directory_separator", which was yielding nothing productive (that is, until I posted this thread :P).